# How to System.Data.SQLite Interop.dll on Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I get the following problem every time I try to run my mobile application:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: 
'SQLite.Interop.dll assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)'
```

**To put this in some context:**
I am developing on `Xamarin.Forms [4.3.0]` (in this case running the build on `Android 9.0 x86`). The client-side library runs on `.NET Standard 2.0` and I have installed [System.Data.SQLite.Core (1.0.112)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/1.0.112) from `NuGet`.

When you look up my problem, you will find people saying to put the `SQLite.Interop.dll`'s into the `x86/x64` folders.
 But when looking for these files there are none for `.NET` Standard at all, only for `.NET Framework`. I tried using the `SQLite.Interop.dll`'s from the precompiled statically-linked binaries from the `.NET Framework 4.6` version.

[Screenshot of the project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnkhL.png)

Same error though.

Unfortunately, it is not possible for me to switch the `SQLite` library as I am porting a desktop version to mobile which uses this lib.

Comment: You are running `Xamarin Forms` 1.3? On an `Android` 9 device? I don't think that's even possible! And that too with .Net Standards! In any case Which SQLite NuGet package are you using?

Comment: Sorry, 1.3.0 refers to Xamarin.Essentials not Forms, which is 4.3.0.908675.
Version of SQLite is linked in the question.

Comment: Are you using the correct nuget package for SQLite? i.e. https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/1.7.302-beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if they have not made a mess in the classes and functions you need to port you can use "Microsoft.Data.SQLite", there is a difference but is not as far away from usable as the crazy nonsense you need to do with  "SQLite-Net-Pcl"

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the excellent answer.
I was using sqlite.net-pcl package and getting strange errors and searching web for anwers and not finding any that works.
I added the Microsft.Data.Sqlite and Bingo! All my problems were solved. I just followed the syntax posted at:
https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/main/samples/snippets/standard/data/sqlite/HelloWorldSample/Program.cs