# System.Data.SQLite (.NET) on Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a project that uses the NuGet package `System.Data.SQLite` for accessing the DB.

At compile time all works fine, but at runtime when I initialize the connection this error occurs:

> System.DllNotFoundException: SQLite.Interop.dll

I have tried to install the NuGet package `System.Data.SQLite.Core` but nothing changed.

How can I solve this? Anyone has found this error too?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the tags and the dependency of the package, it seems the package doesn't support Xamarin. In addition, there were two existed case which had the same problem. You can check this [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510552/xamarin-forms-system-data-sqlite) [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559717/how-to-system-data-sqlite-interop-dll-on-xamarin-forms).

Both of them used the `Microsoft.Data.SQLite` instead of the `System.Data.SQLite`. So you can also choose to use this package.